# Relative shadow sizes using drawingContext in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I'm having issues keeping my shadows consistent across different resolutions using the following:

```
  drawingContext.shadowOffsetY = 0;
  drawingContext.shadowBlur = w(0.01);
  drawingContext.shadowColor = 'black';
```

where

```
function w(val) {if (val == null) return width;return width * val;}
```

defines the relative size .

Any tips on how to keep tie the size of the shadow to the resolution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A ratio of the display with makes sense (at least for square compositions), but you might also want to support different display densities (e.g. for Apple Retina displays, smart phones, etc.). To do this look into:

- [`displayDensity()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/displayDensity)
- [`pixelDensity()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixelDensity)

Comment: Thanks. I did end up using pixelDensity() when I was working on this - took some tinkering, but it worked in the end.

Comment: @AntonE What was your final solution. I'm having the same problem.